# Android: after loading data many times in webview appear white page

Tags: android

when I load some data in web view many times that white page appears ...just scroll it the data is return back..Am notice this issues on android 4.x ...I test it in android  2.3.3 webview work fine

what I can do to prevent this issues ?

Comment: I fix my problem with makeing scroll to page with javascript  after loading is finish

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue and finally solved but I am not sure why. Things that make it work was:

1)

When I finish with a WebView onDestroy of activity/fragment I have:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (isFinishing()) {
      if (myWebView != null) {
        myWebView.destroy();
        myWebView = null;
      }
    }
}
```

2)

I render the code via `myWebView .loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html_sourse, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);` instead of `myWebView.loadData(Uri.encode(html_sourse), "text/html", "utf-8");`. When I am using the second line with an embedded css stylish inside html code page does not appear, changing to the first one (loadDataWithBaseURL) and adding to the html code a css from asset folder page appeared. I cannot understand why but works for me!

3) (optional)

Sometimes it is helpful to use clears if you do not care about keeping history:

```
   myWebView.clearHistory();
   myWebView.clearCache(true);
```